# Is the growth of the binomial coefficient function factorial or polynomial

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, binomial-coefficients

I have written an algorithm that given a list of words, must check each unique combination of four words in that list of words (regardless of order).

The number of combinations to be checked, `x`, can be calculated using the binomial coefficient i.e. `x = n!/(r!(n-r)!)` where `n` is the total number of words in the list and `r` is the number of words in each combination, which in my case is always 4, therefore the function is `x = n!/(4!(n-4)!) = n!/(24(n-4)!)`. Therefore as the number of total words, `n`, increases the number of combinations to be checked, `x`, therefore **increases factorially** right?

What has thrown me is that WolframAlpha was able to rewrite this function as `x = (n^4)/24 − (n^3)/4 + (11.n^2)/24 − n/4`, so now it would appear to grow **polynomially** as `n` grows? So which is it?!

[Here is a graph to visualise the growth of the function (the letter x is switched to an l)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBnng.png)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a fixed value of r, this function is O(n^r). In your case, r = 4, it is O(n^4). This is because most of the terms in the numerator are canceled out by the denominator:

```
n!/(4!(n-4)!) 
   = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)...(3)(2)(1) 
     -------------------------------------------
     4!(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)...(3)(2)(1)

   = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)
     ----------------
           4!
```

This is a 4th degree polynomial in n.